# Getting parameter values from Callablestatement

Tags: java, jdbc, ibm-midrange, callable-statement

I have lots of stored procedure calls in my app and we are using callable statements. At times we need to debug the parameters being passed to the stored proc, there is no easy way but to write code print all the values coming from the entity object.

So I was trying to make a generic function which will take in the callable statement signature, and the callable statement object after execution and for the SQL which was executed and print in logs for debugging. I wrote the following code, but its throwing sql exception "Parameter type not valid" on switch case 1's cs.getString.

Here the parameter type is 1 as retrieved from cs metadata, and as per the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Types.CHAR) the constant 1 is for CHAR, which should map to string in java. Even my actual set parameter for this stored procedure is also using String, which works fine, so why getString is failing with this exception?

I am using AS400 driver.

```
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("{ call ").append(storProcName)
                .append(" (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) }");
        cs = connection.prepareCall(sb.toString());
        // Get and set all parameters
        cs.executeUpdate();
        ParameterMetaData paramd = cs.getParameterMetaData();
        int index, type;
        for (int i = 1; i < paramd.getParameterCount(); i++) {
            type = paramd.getParameterType(i);
            index = sb.indexOf("?");
            if (paramd.getParameterMode(i) == ParameterMetaData.parameterModeIn) {
                switch (type) {
                case 1:
                    sb = sb.replace(index, index + 1, "'" + cs.getString(i)
                            + "'");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What exception? Include the stacktrace

Comment: @Mark Exception was "Parameter type not valid". As I mentioned in the answer below, I am going to work on this problem later

Answer (score 3):

In your example above, the getString() method can only be called on an output parameter.

Have you tried using the driver's tracing feature to display the parameter values?   If you are using the toolbox driver, information about tracing can be found here:
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1018744

If you are using the native JDBC driver, information about trace can be found here: 
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1019479

Comment: For now I am printing all parameters passed to it. I will try your suggestion sometime later.